# Image overlay is transparent

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am trying to create a short and simple animation. I have 2 scenes, one a coin with a logo on it, and the other with an abstract background. When I go into the compositor to render it, the coin with the logo is transparent and I don't know to to fix it.
[image: blender scene open in compositor]

Comment: Don't use add. Use Alpha over to lay one image on top of another using the alpha channel of one of them.

Comment: Make sure on the Film section the Transparent box is enabled.

Comment: Thank you. I did not have the transparent box on.